# Find $dy$ and evaluate $dy$ given $y=e^\frac{x}{10}$ , $x = 0$ and $dx = 0.1$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question below but I missed this day of class maybe someone can show me how to approach?

Find $dy$ and evaluate $dy$ for the given values of $x$ and $dx$

1. $\displaystyle y=e^\frac{x}{10}$
2. $\displaystyle x = 0$ and $dx = 0.1$

Comment: Well, it seems like you should recall
$$ \mathrm{d}y=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x$$
From there, it should be straightforward to solve...

Answer (score 3):

With differentials, it's an abuse of notation, but the answer is that
$$ \mathrm{d}y=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x$$
Since $\mathrm{d}x$ is impossible to use, we make the approximation $\Delta x\approx\mathrm{d}x$.

For us, $\Delta x=0.1$. Now, we find the derivative
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{x/10}=\frac{1}{10}e^{x/10}.$$
Then we plug in the data:
$$\mathrm{d}y\approx \left.\left(\frac{1}{10}e^{x/10}\right)\Delta x\right|_{x=0}$$
which means we are evaluating the parenthetic term when $x=0$, and multiply by $\Delta x=0.1$.

Now we have to just plug these things in to find:
$$\begin{align}\left.\left(\frac{1}{10}e^{x/10}\right)\Delta x\right|_{x=0}&=\left(\frac{1}{10}e^{0}\right)0.1\\
&=0.01\end{align}$$
Thus $\mathrm{d}y\approx 0.01$.

Comment: Precisely how is it an abuse of notation? I recall reading about this, but it has now escaped me. Oh, and wouldn't it be best to write:
$$
\begin{align}
dy&\approx\left. \left(\frac{1}{10}e^{\frac{x}{10}}\right)\Delta x\right|_{x=0}\\
\left. \left(\frac{1}{10}e^{\frac{x}{10}}\right)\Delta x\right|_{x=0}&=\left(\frac{1}{10}e^{0}\right)0.1\\
\left(\frac{1}{10}e^{0}\right)0.1&=1.
\end{align}
$$
?

Comment: Because the notation treats differentials like $\mathrm{d}x$ "as if" they were numbers, and could have 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\color{red}{\mathrm{d}x}}\color{red}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
which is illegal mathematics. The result is right, the reasoning fallacious :(

Comment: Oh, right. They're not even algebraic quantities since they're simply a notational convention just like $\int$. Am I following you?

Comment: Exactly right! :)

Comment: Isn't the answer $\frac1{10}0.1=0.01$?

Comment: @robjohn: one day, I will remember arithmetic ;) Thanks!

Comment: @Limitless: thanks for the advice on typesetting :) I agree, having exactly one relational operator per equation is good; but once I got started, I just got too lazy to stop and sort it out :p

Comment: @AlexNelson, you're welcome. Also, thanks to robjohn for understanding arithmetic. It constantly eludes me, and I find myself running to fields, rings, and groups for comfort. :P